# Split array values using explode

Tags: php, arrays, string

I need to use the explode function for white spaces in the `$str`, after loading content of txt file into `$str`, but it doesn't seem to work well:

```
$filename='acct.txt';
$str=file_get_contents($filename);

print_r (explode("\t",$str));
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( [0] => 101 [1] => 345.23 102 [2] => 43.2 103 [3] => 0 104 [4] => 33 )

print_r (explode(" ",$str));
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( [0] => 101 [1] => 345.23 102 [2] => 43.2 103 [3] => 0 104 [4] => 33 )
```

The file contains this:

```
101 345.23
102 43.2
103 0
104 33
```

How should I change it to get one element at a time?
ie:

```
Array ( [0] => 101 [1] => 345.23  [2] => 102 ....[8]=>33)
```

Thanks for any Help!

Comment: first explode with `\n` and then with empty space `" "` using foreach ofcource

Comment: Remember your last array value is not [8]=>33 but [7]=>33.  Array key starts with 0.

Comment: write some code, a for loop and a foreach.

Comment: Thanks Toby Allen, Saurabh and Amit-

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can read the file line by line using `fgets()`. get a row of arrays and then flatten it. There may be more shortcut but this works for me.

```
<?php

function flatArray($array) {
 $arrayValues = array();
 foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator( new RecursiveArrayIterator($array)) as $val) {
  $arrayValues[] = $val;
 }
 return $arrayValues;
}

$handle = fopen("acct.txt", "r");//YOur file location
$rows = array();
if ($handle) {
    while (($str = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        // process the line read.
        $rows[] = explode(" ",$str);
    }
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
} 

$flatarray = flatArray($rows);


var_dump($flatarray);
```

Comment: this is not the question he is asking.

Comment: @TobyAllen Then what do you think he asked? What result he needed you will get exactly the same answer. Where is the issue. Without testing the code you negatively voted this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that if you have multiple delimeters(newline and space) you have to use preg_split function instead of explode.So your code should look like this:

```
$filename='acct.txt';
$str=file_get_contents($filename);

print_r (preg_split( '/( |\r\n|\r|\n)/', $str ));
```

Which is going to print:

```
Array ( [0] => 101 [1] => 345.23 [2] => 102 [3] => 43.2 [4] => 103 [5] => 0   [6] => 104 [7] => 33 )
```

**EDIT:**

Although the above regex works fine, in is much simpler to use something like this instead:

```
preg_split( '/(\s+)/', $str )
```

which has the exact same output but is much more elegant.

Comment: Thanks for the answers -everyone!'